# I am getting 'Index was outside the bounds of the array' while migrating data from Sage 100 CRM to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssis, dynamics-crm, sage-crm

My company is using Sage CRM and wants me to create a batch job to transport the data from Sage 100 to Dynamics 365 every midnight. They also want me to have the CRM data inside SQL Server first and then migrate that data to Dynamics 365.

I have tried to use the import/export wizard of SQL Server by creating source for ODBC driver datasource (my datasource is the server database path for sage data) and in the destination I provided driver for OLE DB provider for SQL but while I started the import for a single table, I get the following error:

> TITLE: SQL Server Import and Export Wizard
>
> Column information for the source and the destination data could not be retrieved, or the data types of source columns were not mapped correctly to those available on the destination provider(left side of arrow being a source and right one being destination).
>
> "AP_ACHCheckEntry" -> `AP_ACHCheckEntry`:
>
> Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Then I figured out other way using a linked server as mentioned in their forum. Now what I get is data in tables but I can't see their schema inspite of using linked server queries maybe because of data type mismatch( even date is coming as binary datatype in SSIS package while I try data migration using SSIS). Here is a snapshot of the linked server:

[image]

As you can see, I can't expand the table for AP_ACHCheckEntry.

I am literally stuck for weeks and moreover Sage asks our company to pay for the support help. Can anyone help me regarding this?

Comment: My recommendation is to pay for the support.  A migration from one product to another is potentially a HUGE undertaking and likely out of scope for Stackoverflow.

Comment: Are you trying to load data directly into the CRM SQL database? If so, that is unsupported.

Comment: @Aron, you are right. I got it by a different method.